# How to get Chutzpah to discover Typescript files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, chutzpah

I'm utterly stuck: Heres my directory:

```
chutzpah.json
src/
--tests/
----example-test.ts
----test.js
```

//chutzpah.json

```
{
    "Framework": "mocha",
    "MochaInterface": "bdd",
    "TestHarnessReferenceMode": "AMD",
    "TestHarnessLocationMode": "SettingsFileAdjacent",
    "TypeScriptModuleKind": "AMD",
    "References" : [
        {"Path" : "../../libs/require.js" }, //present, not used yet
        { "Path": "../../node_modules/chai/chai.js", "IsTestFrameworkFile": "true" },
        {"Path" : "./config.js" } //blank, for future use
    ],
    "Tests" : [
      {"Path": "./src/tests"}
    ]
}
```

//example-test.ts

```
mocha.setup('bdd');

var expect = chai.expect;
var assert = chai.assert;

describe("MODULE 1", function() {
    it("String doesnt equal number", function() {
        expect('2').to.not.equal(2);
    });
});
```

//test.js

```
var expect = chai.expect
describe("A test suite", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
    });
    afterEach(function () {
    });
    it('should pass', function () {
        expect(true).to.be.true;
    });
});
```

Why can't it discover my example-test.ts in Chutzpah's/VS's test explorer? It does find test.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the visual studio plug-in is set to look for .ts files. Tools->Options->Chutzpah->Unit Test Explorer:
[image]

Comment: I can't see Testing Mode option. Neither setting.

Comment: This was removed and all you need is to use chutzpah.json file to filter .

Comment: I am using   this in chutzpah.json  {
"Compile": {
    "Mode": "External",
    "Extensions": [".ts"],
    "ExtensionsWithNoOutput": [".d.ts"]
   },
  "References": [
    {"Includes": ["*/Scripts/app/*.ts"], "Excludes": ["*/Scripts/app/*.d.ts"] }
  ],
  "Tests": [
    { "Includes": ["*/Scripts/Tests/*.ts"], "Excludes": ["*/Scripts/Tests/*.d.ts"] }
  ]
},  
yet not working